# Last block in flow body at the bottom on last page

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

How can I have the last `fo:block` in `fo:flow` body aligned at the bottom of the last page?

I do not mean footer section on each page, it is ok, but I want to have the last block in flow body at the bottom on last page.

The content of flow body is diverse and I do not know, what will be the height of this last block section.

Is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: Another possible solution from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020403/4453460): use a *footnote*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AH Formatter, you could make the last block float to the bottom of the page.

---

You may be able to put the last block inside an `fo:block-container` and absolutely position the `fo:block-container` at the bottom of the page.

---

You can put the last block in a footer that appears only on the last page:

- Make a separate `fo:simple-page-master` just for the last page
- Use an `fo:region-after` with a difference `master-name` value on that page
- Specify `display-align="after"` on the `fo:region-after` to make sure that its content appears at the bottom
- In your `fo:page-sequence-master`, use an `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` that includes an `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` early in the alternatives that has `page-position="last"` and that selects your page master for the last page
- In the `fo:page-sequence`, make an `fo:static-content` with a `master-reference` that matches the `flow-name` of the `xsl:region-after` of the `fo:simple-page-master` for the last page
- Put the last block content in that `fo:static-content`

Comment: Thanx, but something is wrong (sure my code) :)

Is it probel I'm using Ibex PDF Creator?

Comment: Please update the question to include a minimal sample of your code that shows the problem. So far, between @Ifurini and me, you've got five possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: My code is here (I can't insert it right here - too long):

http://www.xmlgen.cz/tmp/last-block-bottom-last-page.fo

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick that should work (I successfully tested it with FOP 2.3):

```
<fo:block keep-with-previous.within-page="always" 
    keep-together.within-page="always"
    space-before.minimum="1cm" 
    space-before.optimum="30cm" 
    space-before.maximum="30cm">
    Text at the end of the last page
</fo:block>
```

- this block will be placed in the last page, together with (at least a piece of) the preceding block
- it will not be split between pages even if it contains a lot of text, or other blocks (many thanks to user [joH1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6337519/joh1) for this suggestion)
- the optimal space between it and the previous line is greater than the body region height, but the minimum space is much smaller, so it can be "squeezed" (you may want to adjust the minimum value according to your preferences)
- the result is that the formatter will place the whole last block in the page as far as possible from the previous block, which is at the bottom of the body region

Comment: One can add `keep-together.within-page="always"` if the block to put on the bottom has several nested blocks

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old post, but I encountered the same issue and your trick worked, I just needed to add this attribute to make it perfect :)