# displaying footer on last page

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i have a dynamic pdf that can have multiple pages. at the moment i want footer to only display in last page instead of all the pages.

this code displays in all the pages.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master conditional-page-master-reference="first" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="10mm" margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm" margin-top="10mm"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="10mm" margin-left="1cm"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence conditional-page-master-reference="first">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
    <fo:block>I need my footer disclaimer here</fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `fo:page-sequence` referring to a single `fo:simple-page-master`, you want it to point to an `fo:page-sequence-master` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence-master) that has sub-elements for selecting specific `fo:simple-page-master` based on where the page will be in its page sequence.

In your case, you want to select a `fo:simple-page-master` for the last page that has an `fo:region-after` with a distinct `region-name`.  Your `fo:static-content` in the `fo:page-sequence` should use the same region name so that the disclaimer is directed only to that `fo:region-after`.

Examples of `page-position="last"' (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-position) include:

- "Page masters for first, last, and only pages" in the "XSL-FO Samples" at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297851/4092205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28382375/4092205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791914/4092205